# Thread pool size in standard verticle in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

In vert.x, do we need to pass thread pool size while deploying standard verticle.
If no, how we are able to use executeBlocking() which runs on a worker thread (other than event loop thread) in standard verticle ?

Answer (score 2):

Vert.x has a default worker thread pool that is associated with the `Vertx` instance, and is shared by all Verticles. When you use `vertx.executeBlocking(...)`, that pool will be used to execute the callback you provide. You can specify the size of that pool via [`VertxOptions.setWorkerPoolSize(int size)`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setWorkerPoolSize-int-) when you create your Vertx instance if you want, but it will default to 20 threads if you don't.

The Vert.x documentation talks a bit about this [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code).